# iPod touch overheats and won't turn on

Tags: ipod-touch

The other day, I was mad so I took my anger out on my blanket and come to think of it, my iPod touch 5 was inside of it and I didn't realise it until I took it out. It was overheated so much, so I put it in a case so I wouldn't burn myself. When I put my usb port in, it showed a black screen and it says its charging with low battery, but when i take it out, none of the buttons work and it wont turn on, what can I do?

I had all my photos on it and now it wont do anything at all! theres a hole in the back of my iPod touch back case and I'm worried it cant be fixed.

Comment: Did you use iCloud to sync the photos or use a cloud service, like Dropbox, to backup them up?

Comment: Can you provide a photos of "the hole in the back of my iPod touch"?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've shorted or actually damaged the battery.

Take it to an Apple Store to be checked out immediately. Li-ion batteries can catch fire or explode if damaged.

[image]

<sup>Yes, this one's a Samsung... they're just far easier to find pictures of ;-)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that you haven't charged it long enough, so that is why it is appearing "unresponsive" when you try to turn it back on. It is unlikely that you would have done such significant damage to your iPod by hitting your blanket (unless you used other methods involving blunt and heavy object(s)).

Comment: could that be that case? i didnt even do extreme damage to it i let it charge overnight and it didnt even turn on at all it stayed the same

Comment: No, it definitely should have turned on then. In that case you might have shorted your battery in some way, like Tetsujin suggested, but I still find it odd that it even got damaged. Can you tell us more about the device's condition before, or anything you did with the device before you hit it?